# Is there a way to change the nested layout parameters of android widget programatically?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget, layoutparams

I would like to know if there is any way to change the `width` and `height` of nested `Layout` in android widget `xml` programatically just like that of `LayoutParams` in normal activity?

I'm planning to make a custom progress bar with the `LineraLayouts` hence i need to change the `width` of one layout to display the change

Answer (score 0):

The type of the `LayoutParams` you must use is specified by the type of Layout that encapsulates the thing you want to change params for.

So for example if you want to change `LayoutParams` for your `LinearLayout` you need to check what's the Layout type that encapsulates it. In your case `LinearLayout` is being encapsulated by `RelativeLayout` so you need to use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` instead of `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`.

`LinearLayout` inside `RelativeLayout` in your xml file (activity_main.xml). Use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` to solve this issue.

Change this:

```
ll.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(100,200));
```

to:

```
ll.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100,200));
```

Comment: but how do you define which layout you want to change (i have already mentioned i have nested layout)? and i'm asking in case of widgets not simple activity

Comment: But i ain't asking for activity, please read the question carefully, if it were activity i wouldn't have asked in the first case

Answer (score -1):

You have to use this way to find nested layout and change layout params.

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(view.getId());
LinearLayout rLGreen = ((LinearLayout) button.getParent());
rLGreen.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

It may be help you!!

Comment: Please read the question, i'm not asking how to do it in case of `activity` rather i'm asking how to do the process in case of `widget`